# Generate certificate pfx from file .crt and file .p7b actalis SSL DV

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl, certificate

I have following files:

- 5658747.crt
- 5658747.p7b

I want to generate file pfx for import ssl in website iis.
I tried to generate the private key with openssl ( win ) and with the procedure for importing the certificate into a "personal" local computer, but to no avail.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38 The private key was already generated when you tried to request this certificate and cannot be re-generated another time. So, at this moment you should try your best to recall where you saved it. If you cannot find it any more, then you will have to go through everything from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the actalis,the private key and the csr are created from this link:

https://extwebra.actalis.it/portal/uapub/tools/generatecsr

After import private key and crt for generate a pfx with this tool
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate pfx file...

Double click on .crt file, then Details|Copy To File to .cer file (X.509).

Open Control Panel|Internet Options|Content, click Certificates|Intermediate Certification Authorities, then click Import and navigate to 5658747.p7b and complete import.

Then in IIS manager, click your main server, open Server Certificates feature.  Then click "Complete Certificate Request" under Actions, and import your newly created .cer file.

Finally, bind you new certificate to your website.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I followed all the steps, but after import .cer file, i see the file for a few seconds on the screen 'Server Certificates', and in site bindings isn't present.